# How to combine and handle data dictionary in list of complex array dict data

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, arraylist

I have a big problem. This is my data.The data structure looks like this. It include metric_name, date_time and data of date_time in metric_name.

```py
{
 "metric_name 1":{
    "date_time 1": [{data server 1}, ... ,{data server n}],
    "date_time 2": [{data server 1}, ... ,{data server n}],
    ...
  },
 "metric_name 2":{
    "date_time 1": [{data server 1}, ... ,{data server n}],
    "date_time 2": [{data server 1}, ... ,{data server n}],
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

- Data detail in below, I have 3 server and get data in 2 day [2022-03-25, 2022-03-26]

```py
data = {
  "cpu": {
    "2022-03-25": [
      {
        "cpu_usage": 0.2, "name": "server01", "timestamp": "2022-03-25"
      },
      {
        "cpu_usage": 0.3, "name": "server02", "timestamp": "2022-03-25"
      },
      {
        "cpu_usage": 0.25, "name": "server03", "timestamp": "2022-03-25"
      },
    ],
   "2022-03-26": [
      {
        "cpu_usage": 0.15, "name": "server01", "timestamp": "2022-03-26"
      },
      {
        "cpu_usage": 0.2, "name": "server02", "timestamp": "2022-03-26"
      },
      {
        "cpu_usage": 0.15, "name": "server03", "timestamp": "2022-03-26"
      },
    ],
  },
 "ram": {
    "2022-03-25": [
      {
        "ram_usage": 0.4, "name": "server01", "timestamp": "2022-03-25"
      },
      {
        "ram_usage": 0.5, "name": "server02", "timestamp": "2022-03-25"
      },
      {
        "ram_usage": 0.5, "name": "server03", "timestamp": "2022-03-25"
      },
    ],
   "2022-03-26": [
      {
        "ram_usage": 0.7, "name": "server01", "timestamp": "2022-03-26"
      },
      {
        "ram_usage": 0.6, "name": "server02", "timestamp": "2022-03-26"
      },
      {
        "ram_usage": 0.5, "name": "server03", "timestamp": "2022-03-26"
      },
    ],
  }
}
```

I will for loop this data and compare each date_time of metric_name. Every date_time is list data and includes data of all server.

I want to combine and average the data for each date_time.

- Example: date_time "2022-03-25" of metric_name is cpu. I will average data cpu_usage of 3 servers and combine data. Beside, I remove key and value  "name"
- cpu_usage =  (0.2+0.3+0.25)/3 = 0.25

It will look like

```py
"cpu": {
    "2022-03-25": [
      {
        "cpu_usage": 0.25, "timestamp": "2022-03-25"
      }
    ],
```

**Desired result**

```py
output = {
  "cpu": {
    "2022-03-25": [
       {
        "cpu_usage": 0.25, "timestamp": "2022-03-25"
       }
    ],
   "2022-03-26": [
      {
        "cpu_usage": 0.166, "timestamp": "2022-03-26"
      }
    ],
  },
 "ram": {
    "2022-03-25": [
      {
        "ram_usage": 0.46, "timestamp": "2022-03-25"
      }
    ],
   "2022-03-26": [
      {
        "ram_usage": 0.6, "timestamp": "2022-03-26"
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

Note: I use python 3.9

I hope someone will help me. Thank you very muck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remark: the average memory usage is formatted to 3 decimal places and is a *string*. In case replace `f'{stat:0.3f}'` with `round(stat, 3)` which will be a float.

```
def prittify(data):
    new_data = {}
    for memory_type, d in data.items():
        new_data[memory_type] = {}

        for date, d_list in d.items():
            stat = sum(i[f'{memory_type}_usage'] for i in d_list) / len(l)

            new_data[memory_type][date] = {f'{memory_type}_usage': f'{stat:0.3f}', 'timestamp': date}

    return new_data

d = prittify(data)

print(d)
```

Output

```
{'cpu': {'2022-03-25': {'cpu_usage': '0.250', 'timestamp': '2022-03-25'}, '2022-03-26': {'cpu_usage': '0.167', 'timestamp': '2022-03-26'}}, 'ram': {'2022-03-25': {'ram_usage': '0.467', 'timestamp': '2022-03-25'}, '2022-03-26': {'ram_usage': '0.600', 'timestamp': '2022-03-26'}}}
```